# Network Can't see a Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: file, networking

I inherited a script that moves documents from a web server (unix) to a `sharepoint` document library via `robocopy`.

The script looks like this:

```
net use v: \\webserver\share /user:u p
robocopy v:\ "\\internalserver\docs\Indexing Library" /MOV
net use v: /d /yes
exit
```

Now, I can connect to the webserver and browse the files appropriately.  However, when I run robocopy, I get this error:

```
Error 67 - Getting File System Type of Destination \\internalserver\docs\Indexing Library\
The network name cannot be found.
```

Now, I can ping `\\internalserver` and I get a successful response back.  However, if I ping `\\internalserver\docs`, I get an error back.  The `\docs` is the `Sharepoint` document library, so I am not even sure whether I should be able to ping that or not.

Regardless - How can I correct this so I can connect to the network folder?

Comment: is 'webserver' a FQDN or a machine name?

Comment: what OS are you trying to run this script on?

Comment: @DaveWise webserver is an ip address - it's a non-public server that's only used for uploaded documents.

Comment: @DavidLozzi webserver is unix.  internalserver is Windows Server.  There is a 3rd server in the middle that actually runs the script, which is Windows Server as well.

Comment: has it run on this server before?

Comment: @DavidLozzi Yes - The script ran without a problem for awhile (months) - then, just stopped working.  Can you make a Sharepoint library to a drive?

Comment: Yessir! http://davidlozzi.com/2012/05/01/map-a-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-from-windows-server-2008/

Comment: Has the SharePoint list been renamed? Can you re-reference the folder with the SharePoint list? (Add a network folder)

Comment: can you make sure weddav is started on both the client and IIS machine??